# Is it possible to send email if IIS/SMTP agents are not installed on my pc?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtp

Is it possible to send email using asp.net if my local pc dont have IIS/SMTP agent installed. PS I'm using Windows 7

I've tried loads of code: This is what i'm currently using

```
    Dim message As New MailMessage("abc@xyz.com", "pqr.@xyz.com", "SUB: Testing email", "SENDING EMAIL VAI ASP.NET")
    Dim emailClient As New SmtpClient("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX")
    emailClient.Send(message)
    MsgBox("Message Sent")
```

Error message:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]

[SmtpException: Failure sending mail.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP does not have to be installed on the same server but your IP address should be permitted.

You can also use Gmail with your own account as your SMTP server.

Comment: Help! I want to use configured SMTP server, and not the gmail or yahoo one. My code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am using. (it's C# but you can convert it)

```
static readonly string EmailSendFrom = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSendFrom"];
static readonly string EmailDisplayName = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailDisplayName";
static readonly string EmailPassword = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailPassword"];

 public static void SendEmail(string emailHtmlContent, string emailRecipients, string emailSubject, bool addBbc)
        {
            var @from = EmailSendFrom;                               
            var to = emailRecipients;

            var mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(to);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(@from, EmailDisplayName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            mail.Subject = emailSubject;
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Body = emailHtmlContent;
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;                       
            var client = new SmtpClient
            {
                Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(@from, EmailPassword),
                Port = 587,
                Host = "myhost.name.co.il",
                EnableSsl = false
            };

            client.Send(mail);
        }
```